# JSP & Html User Interface

Tags: html, jsp

I developed a system using JSP with Java Studio Creator and connect it with Data Base. But after finishing it , the interface was not so good and I want to use the html coding for the interface only. How can I do that ? .

Because I have an html template and copy paste it in the Java Studio Creator in the JSP page and it gives me an exception. I want to catch the line where I can go through it to handle this issue .

Comment: I'm afraid, you will need to learn quite a bit more about programming in general and the Java language in particular.. Also, you forgot to post your exception!

Comment: Thanks 'nfexhner' for your comment , no problem I can learn if it's help me , but the problem is that I'm afraid to learn things will not help me . All the exceptions are regarding the termination of the tag !!!.

Comment: You still haven't posted them. [Please read this article on how to ask good questions.](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)